# Remove first 27 characters from each line in richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

How would I go about removing the first 27 characters from each line in a richtextbox?

I have tried

```
For Each i In RichTextBox1.Lines
        i = RichTextBox1.Text.Remove(0, 27)
    Next
```

Comment: You try it first.  Then post what you've tried if it fails.  Then you get help.

Comment: I have been trying, this is my last resort. Thanks for being inviting to stackoverflow.

Comment: Then where is the code you've tried? We're all happy to help if you've tried first.  That's why you're getting down voted.  (I haven't down voted)

Comment: Updated question with the code that failed to work for me. I know it's probably an easy fix or explanation as to why it will not work but it's not coming to me.

Comment: Is the data just text? If so try using a multi-line textbox and the Lines() method below. Using RichTextBox just complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **preserve formatting** already in the RichTextBox, then do it this way:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
        Dim index As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
        RichTextBox1.Select(index, Math.Min(27, RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Length))
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = ""
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating through the `Lines` property and trying to change each line individually, try assigning the `Lines` property a new array like this:

**Updated to handle lines less than 27 characters**

```
RichTextBox1.Lines = RichTextBox1.Lines.Select(Function(line) If(line.Length >= 27, line.Remove(0, 27), line)).ToArray()
```

Instead of `String.Remove()` you can also using `String.Substring()`

```
RichTextBox1.Lines = RichTextBox1.Lines.Select(Function(line) If(line.Length >= 27, line.Substring(27), line)).ToArray()
```

Comment: It won't make a ton of difference, but as far as I know using Substring  instead of Remove will speed this up a bit

Comment: @Saragis I figured that, but didn't want to defer to far from what the OP was already trying.  I'll add that as another possibility.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am getting an "Index and length must refer to a location within the string." error though, which is not making to much sense seeing as 0, 27 is the 27 is the length and the index is the location.

Comment: @user3166518 You sure all of your lines are at least 27 characters in length?

Comment: Each line is at least a minimum of around 30, however I just noticed that there is an extra line at the end of the rtb which is probably where the error is coming from.